# Search for text in Word Endnotes

Tags: ms-word, wildcard

Hello: I am trying to perform either a regular search or wildcard search in Word, specifically in the Endnotes.
Here is what I am searching for:
[Endnote Reference][space][text....][:]

Here is an example of what the endnote might look like:
12 Text in my endnote ending with a colon: More text but not what I want.

So what I want to do is select all the text (plus colon) following the Endnote Reference + space (i.e., Text in my endnote ending with a colon:) and add bold/italics.
I've tried using the advance search where I search for:
^e^?: --> doesn't work (I'd like to make the "any character" a bunch of characters until the : is reached)
Wildcard search does not allow the use of ^e so I tried:
*L --> that gives way too much and then also doesn't work.

Any feedback is much appreciated. I could accomplish this in Perl, but not in Word.
thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need Regex for this. All you need is a *wildcard* Find, where:

```
Find = ^2 [!^13]@:
```

Using VBA for what you're trying to do:

```
Sub Demo()
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
With ActiveDocument.StoryRanges(wdEndnotesStory)
  With .Find
    .ClearFormatting
    .Replacement.ClearFormatting
    .Text = "^2 [!^13]@:"
    .Replacement.Text = ""
    .Forward = True
    .Format = False
    .Wrap = wdFindStop
    .MatchWildcards = True
  End With
  Do While .Find.Execute
    .Start = .Endnotes(1).Range.Start
    .Style = "MyBoldItalicCharacterStyle"
    .Collapse wdCollapseEnd
  Loop
End With
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

Comment: That worked like a charm! Thank you so much for responding and I will give you a 5-star rating!

Comment: «I will give you a 5-star rating» Better still, check the check box next to my answer, in order to mark it as an *accepted* answer.

Comment: Did it! Let me know if that went through. Thanks again!